# Query to Traverse tree mysql

Tags: mysql, tree

I developed an edge list model graph on mysql. I found same procedure on http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html to traverse the tree.

But I need a particular query that given three random nodes I recognize if they are part (subpath) of a descendent path in the general tree.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying a database representation of a tree (MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362688/querying-a-database-representation-of-a-tree-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a function "has_parent(this_node, looking_for)" that recursively (i.e. by calling itself) queries  up the tree to solve the problem.