# How to Implementing jquery on Tree Checkbox (build from scratch - no plugin)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I don't know if the following Hierarchical Data is Adjacency list or Nested List model. What i know is, it's easy to collect the hierarchical data. For example,

to get all the tree then use :
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY  trn ASC

to get all the tree start from item News (7) :
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE trn LIKE '%+7+%'

It just a single query, instead of doing looping parent-child query.

```
catID   cat_title           status      trn         trn_level
7       News                publish     +7          0
8       Artikel             publish     +8          0
9       Public Training     draft       +7+9        1
10      Coorporate Mgt      draft       +8+10       1
16      MS Based On IS      draft       +7+9+16     2
17      Inhouse Training    draft       +7+17       1
18      MS                  publish     +7+17+18    2
19      SM                  publish     +7+17+19    2
```

So... my jQuery problem is:
The datas above will produce checkbox html like the following :

```
News 
   Inhouse Training
      MS
      SM
   Public Training
      MS Based On IS
Artikel
   Coorporate Management

<ul class="categoriesTree">
<li>
<?php str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",$row['trn_level']); ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="<?php echo $row['catID']; ?>" class="<?php echo $row['trn']; ?">
<?php echo $row['cat_title']; ?>
</li>
</ul>
```

How to perform parent-child checked with jQuery. Example : if i checked on item News, i want it will also checked item 
- Inhouse Training
- MS
- SM
- Public Training
- MS Based On IS

Basicly i want to perform a parent child checked, if the child checked first, the the reference parent of the item will also checked, if the parent checked first then all the childs will checked.

I hope what I mean is clear enough :). I know that there are lots of tree plugin ready to use, but i want to understand & build my own from scratch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This DB design is awful. Normalize column trn!. This code will run very slow and cannot use indexes.

Comment: @Johan, why is it so ? would you like to explain it ? thanks.

Comment: `select * from table where columnx like 'gshdg%'` can use an index, because you're searching for the leading chars.  `select * from table where columnx like '%hsdjd%'`  can **never** use an index because you're looking at the middle of the string. This always forces a full table scan making things very slow. Also your looking for chars where you could be using indexed integers. This will make your query go slower and slower as your tables grow. If you normalize the trl column, your runtime will only grow O(log(N)) because you can use the Btree index and an equi-join.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying a database representation of a tree (MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362688/querying-a-database-representation-of-a-tree-mysql)

Comment: @Johan, my question is not about the database, but about jQuery checkbox. However i thank you for remind me about data indexing. My idea to store trailing id in column trn is to easy track the id's attached to it. So what do you suggest on how to normalized it so i can track all the id's attached on each id. Prior i used the adjacency list model wich has ID and ParentID. And to get all the items i have to use a recursive function in my php code. With this current data model i found out the query time much faster than the ALM model. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, faster because you have a small dataset and because you're doing everything in MySQL, as your data grows it will get slower and slower. because it has a O(N log(n)) running time, whereas ALM only has O(log(N)) running time albeit with a larger constant.  You can do ALM completely in MySQL though, no need for post-processing in php.

Comment: @froditus: Back to the original question, here is an example of checking the child and all its siblings: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/8c88V/

Comment: @Brad Christie, Thanks Brad..., Close to that. However my tree check boxes is produced from the data as described from mysql table above. Your example use multi layer <UL>, mine only single <UL>. I use column trn_level value to produce indent on each <LI> element. And your example only from top to down elements. If i clicked / checked on one of the child element, it supposed to checked also the upper level element wich has attached to it. Anyway thank you so much for giving an approach solution for my problem.

Comment: @froditus: So, the database is storing the checked-state? Shouldn't you be performing the "parent is checked, so should this" when you store it then, not error-checking (catching) at the output level?

Comment: @Brad Christie, I've edited my comment above. Yes, it will store the checked state in the database but in a different table. Let's say the table above is table categories and the checked state are going to be stored on post table. This tree categories is shown on a post input form and it fetch the categories from table categories

Comment: no more interested in an answer? would be nice to at least comment on given answers.

Answer (score 0):

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNVu4/2/) for an example.
some explanations:

first:

```
class="<?php echo $row['trn']; ?"
```

that way you'll end up with class names like '+7', which are not valid in css.

as you don't have a proper hierarchy indication in your html yet (using a single UL), i'd recommend using the 'trn_level' field to build classes holding that information:

```
class="level_<?php echo $row['trn_level']; ?"
```

this will make it easier to determine the parent/child relationship for the checkbox logic. to simplify this some more, apply it to the 'LI' instead of the checkbox itself. this will also allow you to define css classes to do the indentation for you (instead of that hacky `&nbsp;` stuff)

the jquery code for checking the checkboxes is quite straight-forward: find all preceding list elements, and check them in case their level is less than the current level. same thing is done for all next elements (having a level greater than the current one).

**NOTE:** for sure the code in my example could be simplified and tweaked some more, but in the end it's not a very elegant solution, as the hierarchy of the items isn't self-explanatory. you should really try to render nested UL's to reflect the hierarchy in HTML instead.